# Nant does not launch nunit2 task

Tags: nunit, nant

I have a very simple class with Watin test which is built and run nicely from Visual Studio.
Now I want to build it and launch with Nant. I've written the following nant .build file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<project name="WatinTests" default="build">
  <property name="build.dir" value="c:WatinTests\bin\" />
  <property name="project.rootdirectory" value="." />
  <property name="solution.dir" value="."/>
  <property name="solution.file" value="${solution.dir}/WatinTests.csproj"/>
  <property name="build.configuration" value="debug" />
  <property name="nant.settings.currentframework" value="net-4.0" />
  <mkdir dir="${build.dir}" />
  <target name="build">
    <exec
      program="${framework::get-framework-directory(framework::get-target-framework())}\msbuild.exe"
      commandline="${solution.file} /t:Clean /p:Configuration=${build.configuration} /v:q"
      workingdir="."
      output="${build.dir}/WatinTests.dll" />
  </target>
  <target name="test" depends="build">
    <nunit2>
      <formatter type="Plain" />
      <test assemblyname="${build.dir}WatinTests.dll" />
    </nunit2>
  </target>
</project>
```

First task is performed successfully - WatinTests.dll file goes to \bin directory.
But test is not launched. Here is the output:

> Buildfile: file:///c:/WatinTests/nant.build Target framework:
>   Microsoft .NET Framework 4.0 Target(s) specified: build test
>
> build:
>
> test:
>
> BUILD FAILED
>
> c:\WatinTests\nant.build(14,6): Failure executing test(s). If you
>   assembly is not built using NUnit version 2.6.0.12051, then ensure you
>   have redirected ass embly bindings. Consult the documentation of the
>    task for more information.
>       Could not load file or assembly 'WatinTests.dll' or one of its dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect
>   format.
>       Could not load file or assembly 'WatinTests.dll' or one of its dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect
>   format.

What is wrong here?

Comment: Have a look at this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3874780/650012).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the [Nant documentation](http://nant.sourceforge.net/release/0.92/help/tasks/nunit2.html), did you add the assembly binding redirection into your app.config :

```
<runtime>
  <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
    <dependentAssembly>
      <assemblyIdentity name="nunit.framework" publicKeyToken="96d09a1eb7f44a77" culture="Neutral" />
      <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-2.2.8.0" newVersion="2.2.8.0" />
    </dependentAssembly>
  </assemblyBinding>
</runtime>
```